# Saucelabs connect Linux - Not recognising the '-u' command

Tags: linux, connect, saucelabs

When trying to start up a tunnel using saucelabs connect, I'm using the standard command within the bin folder:

```
sc -u USERNAME -k API-KEY
```

However, when I run it, an error is thrown saying:

```
sc: invalid option -- 'u'
```

I've tried on windows and it runs perfectly. Any ideas why it can't read the command?

Comment: it's probably a stupid question but are you sure that the "sc" command captured is the path in SauceConnect and not any other linux command?

Answer (score 0):

Probably there's another command in your `PATH` called `sc`. Try this:

```
$ cd <directory where you downloaded Sauce Connect>
$ ./sc -u <username> -k <API key>
```